# Gradle Local Repository to share jars easily?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

So we a re considering Gradle instead of Maven.  What I cant figure out is how to EASILY share built dependencies between completely seperate projects at a local level that will work anywhere.

So imagine I have 2 projects **DBService** and **Middleware**.  **Middleware** depends on **DBService** but they are completely seperate (not sub projects nor multi modules etc...).

I make changes to the **DBService** and then in Maven I could have changes go to local Maven Repo (not global as i need to test them first) using:

```
mvn clean install
```

I then start coding on **Middleware** and import the changes by running the same command as normal (Nice!).  The maven POM requires nothing special at all (besides standard ).  No path to local directory containing the jar in a lib folder (nasty IMHO) or anything else.  it just works (out of the box).

How can I achieve this very simple and very common scenario in Gradle.  I know I can use a local Maven repo but this is this a first class citizen in Gradle?  Does it not need special/ad-hoc, or even worse, environment specific  setup (UGHH) in Gradle?.

Comment: You can run `gradle clean install` as well. It works exactly the same.

Comment: What @Opal mentioned should work, but you need to make sure your projects list `mavenLocal()` as one of their `repositories` in your `build.gradle` file. This will cause Gradle to look at your local maven repo for dependencies. You can also specify a url to a maven-style repo if you want to have a shared one on an internal server.

Comment: You also need to configure snapshot resolving to get the latest artifact every time.

Comment: Take note that use of the `install` task requires applying the 'maven' plugin: `apply plugin: 'maven'`.

Comment: Thanks folks this is very helpful.  Doesnt it mean though that I require Maven.  I was trying to get away from Maven.  So to use gradle alI our Devs need to install Maven and Gradle!  So really Gradle is not a super Maven alternative but a great Maven Wrapper?